# What can I replace with Strings.Mid in C#

Tags: .net

What can I replace with Strings.Mid in C#

Strings.Mid(Filename, Strings.InStrRev(Filename, "\") + 1));

Comment: You're welcome to search for it online and learn. Microsoft even has a manual-like page where they explain what this (and a great many other things) does. A manual page, if you will. Just because it's the holiday season, I have searched for you. [My gift to you](https://www.google.be/search?q=string+mid+c%23). All jokes aside though, please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly as it will vastly improve your chances of getting good answers in return and not have your question downvoted or closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Path.GetFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string.
>   Return Value: The characters after the last directory character in
>   path.

So:

```
Filename = Path.GetFileName(FileName);
```

would give you just the filename, removing the path from the front.